# How do I pause a vlc process from the command line?

Tags: cmd, command, line, vlc

I'd like to pause a vlc process by using the command line.

I start the process with this `vlc -I dummy--quiet music.mp3` and I want to pause it until I play it.

With `vlc --help` I got this `vlc://pause:seconds` but it creates a new process and I want to pause a process already running.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to kill the process of VLC.exe ? or you want to pause it for a certain seconds ?

Comment: Sorry if my sentences are not correct, I don't want to kill it, I want to pause it (when you press the spacebar on vlc for example).

Comment: In this case edit your title and modifiy it by Pause instead of Stop !